# Dropwizard Kotlin "Main method is not static in class" when running java -jar

Tags: kotlin, dropwizard

I am attempting to start my Dropwizard Kotlin application. When running:

```
java -jar target/application-1.0.jar server environment.yml
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Main method is not static in class, please define the main method as: 
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that the `main` method in your application class is defined inside of a companion object with `@JvmStatic`:

```
class MyClass {    
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            Application().run(*args)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

function main can be a top-level function (let's say in a file called `foo.bar.MainApp.kt`):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   Application().run(*args)
}
```

If building and packaging with gradle and the application plugin then configure that with:

```
application {
    mainClassName = "foo.bar.MainAppKt"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
id 'application'
}
mainClassName = 'Main'
```

In Main.kt:

```
class Main {

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```